# Number theory;Mit maths for computer Science

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am reading the book of MIT MATHS FOR COMPUTER SCIENCE.BUT GOT CONFUSED HERE:

> The rule of thumb derived from the Prime Number Theorem says that
>   among 10-digit numbers, about $1$ in $\ln \left(10^{10}\right) \approx 23$
>   is prime.

$10^{10}$ has $11$ digits not $10$ digits.So why we are not using $9,999,999,999$ to calculate prime density?

Comment: If you are going to approximate things very roughly, what would a difference of $1$ out of $10^{10}$ make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has more to do with logarithms. You're absolutely right, the largest 10-digit number is $x=9999999999$. On the other hand $10^{10}-x=1$. Notice that:

$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)=\ln(1+1/x)=1/x+O(1/x^2).$$

If $x=9999999999$, then $1/x\approx 10^{-10}$, which is not only smaller than 1, but tiny as well. If you just put the difference in a calculator you'll see it for yourself. The moral is that logorithms grow very,very slowly when numbers get large.

Comment: So I can take here that in Prime Number Theorem they have taken the  10-digit number , 9999999999 nearly as 10^10.    But in wikipedia page of prime number theorem also they have taken 1000 digit number to be 10^1000.SO it is just an approximation.

Comment: @ShivamChauhan: correct. More precisely though if you want to be "more exact", there can be at most 1 prime in the interval $[x,x+1]$ for $x>2$. In this case $10^{10}$ is not a prime so there's no issue. But the prime number theorem is an approximation in either case.